# Showcase 11 elements in a circle CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this layout with CSS but I just can't seem to figure out how to make it work.
[View Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjxSx.png).

The Layout consists out of a big circle (with information in it) and 11 Circle Elements around it. On Hover, Information about each Element is displayed in the big circle.

I tried a lot of stuff and looked at many answers on here but couldn't find one, that works on our system. We can use plain JS, HTML and CSS (no SCSS).

My current approach is to transform them, but I need to be able to insert img + HoverLink in every outer element. I also don't know how to set  big circle in the middle of this.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-left: 47.5%;
}

.circle div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(32.7deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(32.7deg);
  transform: rotate(32.7deg);
}

.circle:before,
.circle div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  background: gold;
}

.cct1 {
  content: "CCT1";
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="cct1">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```